# Javascript Explanation of order of operations with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

Why would i get a Cannot read property 'name' of null on a ternary operator result that shouldn't hit.  I don't seem to understand the logic and flow of when what gets read when.

This fails

```
 function log(msg) {
            console.log('something' + (log.caller != null) ? log.caller.name: ""+"->" + msg);
        }
```

This works  (moved ternary into its own line)

```
function log(msg) {
            callerName = (log.caller != null) ? log.caller.name: "";
            console.log('something' + callerName +"->" + msg);
        }
```

Then i realized this works (Added parentheses around whole ternary logic)

```
    function log(msg) {        
        console.log('something' + ((log.caller != null) ? log.caller.name : "") +"->" + msg);
    }
```

But then this works too (Removed string before the ternary)

```
function log(msg) {       
        console.log((log.caller != null) ? log.caller.name : "" +"->" + msg);
    }
```

Bonus interesting logic that works... never knew !! would convert to a bool.  Obviously wont work with strict.  (not sure if this is bad practice tho)

```
function log(msg) {       
        console.log('something' + (!!log.caller ? log.caller.name : "") +"->" + msg);
    }
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `!!` and it will work in "strict" mode.

Comment: The `? :` ternary operator has pretty low precedence, so the safe thing to do is parenthesize the whole thing if you're unsure.

Comment: `'something' + (log.caller != null) ? log.caller.name: ""+"->" + msg` is the same as `('something' + (log.caller != null)) ? log.caller.name: ""+"->" + msg`

Comment: ahh. It translates it to that.